# WCF replacement for cross process/machine communication

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a C# application that contains multiple windows services that will need to communicate with each other to pass data around.  These services may be on the same machine but they could be remote.  I looked into using WCF for this purpose but it seems like WCF is too heavy and has a lot of extra configuration that, to me, seems unnecessary (.NET 3.5 is a requirement here, I know that .NET 4 simplified this)

So my question is, what would be the best replacement to WCF, besides the deprecated .NET Remoting that provide this functionality?

Comment: Complaining about the configuration seems a tad petty.  As for performance, NetTCP binding is available in 3.5, so not sure what your concern is there either.

Comment: I was more curious about if there were alternatives and what they may be if any.  Searching the Google always points me back to WCF.  This is coming from someone who usually programs Java, so I'm used to RMI, EJB, etc.

Comment: I reached more or less the same conclusion.I found that the configuration of WCF to be tricky and ill-documented, and under a thrashing,I also found it painfully slow and somewhat reluctant to release memory.Maybe I set it up wrong,but it was not as performant as I'd hoped, and the fix was not apparent in the myriad of configuration option.I ended up writing my own *lightweight* remoting framework which I hope one day to get approval to open-source.It was by no means trivial to implement. Unless you're butting into these kinds of problems,I'd stick with WCF until it *proves* to be problematic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have been using PInvoke to access the Windows RPC runtime for nearly 8 years.  It's wicked fast and very reliable as far as a transport goes.  When combined with a fast serializer like protobuf-csharp-port the resulting communications are rock solid and [very fast](http://csharptest.net/787/benchmarking-wcf-compared-to-rpclibrary/).

So to build this from the ground-up this requires three parts:

1. Google's Protocol Buffers ([protobuf-csharp-port](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)) for serialization.
2. My own [CSharpTest.Net.RpcLibrary](http://csharptest.net/projects/rpclibrary/) for the transport.
3. A bit of glue code to put them together from [protobuf-csharp-rpc](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-rpc/).

These are all available on NuGet in the following packages: [Google.ProtocolBuffers](http://nuget.org/packages/Google.ProtocolBuffers), [CSharpTest.Net.RpcLibrary](http://nuget.org/packages/CSharpTest.Net.RpcLibrary), and [Google.ProtocolBuffers.Rpc](http://nuget.org/packages/Google.ProtocolBuffers.Rpc).

The following is a quick run-down on getting started:

1. define a set of messages and a service using the [Google Protocol Buffer Language](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto).
2. Once you have that defined you will run ProtoGen.exe to generate the service stubs and messages in C#.  Be sure to add the "-service_generator_type=IRPCDISPATCH" to generate the correct service code.
3. Now that you have the generated source files add them to a project and reference the three assemblies from the packages listed above.
4. Lastly take a look at the sample client/server code on the [protobuf-csharp-rpc](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-rpc/) project page.  Replace the "SearchService" with your service name, and you should be ready to run.
5. Optionally change the configuration of the RPC client/server.  The example shows the use of LRPC which is local-host only; however the [DemoRpcLibrary.cs](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-rpc/source/browse/src/ProtocolBuffers.Rpc.Test/DemoRpcLibrary.cs) source file show TCP/IP and Named Pipes as well.

You can always email me (roger @ my user name) for any further information or examples.

**Update**

I wrote a quick startup guide: [WCF replacement for cross process/machine communication](http://csharptest.net/1177/wcf-replacement-for-cross-processmachine-communication/).

Comment: This looks like the alternative I was looking for, Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Andrew Landsverk, see also: http://csharptest.net/1177/wcf-replacement-for-cross-processmachine-communication/

Comment: Hah! Your post confirms everything I suspected about WCF but never got round to measuring. Your solution is very interesting... Definitely an answer worthy of more than +1.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful. Your log4net XSD is also very helpful. So thanks for that too.

Comment: @csharptest.net Thank you for sharing the libray, great work. I am trying to figure out how to deal with long-running operations. The Execute() call is synchronous and theoretically I could refactor the library to split the call/return sequence. Is there a built-in method of "eventing" or server -> client calls? I looked through "Microsoft RPC Programming Guide" by Shirley and Rosenberry, couldn't find

Comment: @csharptest.net (couldn't edit previous comment)  It seems that RpcContext is the direction to dig into. Any plans for adding that to the library?

Comment: It's possible to do async rpc calls, but I've not had the time to add support in.  We tend to use long poll to feed status etc.

Comment: I know this is an old post but i find the numbers in http://csharptest.net/787/benchmarking-wcf-compared-to-rpclibrary/ to be very suspect without any source provided for the benchmarking. And if "wcf_pipes" is actually named pipes, these numbers are even more suspect. There's no way http is going to outperform **in-memory transport**.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into ZeroMQ, it's very lightweight and effective and comes with good C# bindings. (Typing this on my mobile so you'll have to google for it yourself for now, sorry).

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call ZeroMQ lightweight.

Comment: ZeroMQ is very good provided you don't care for a response and aren't worried about messages getting dropped on the floor. Like all queues, only so much backlog can be stored. ZeroMQ's performance in guaranteed delivery and request/response configurations is particularly bad.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [NFX Glue](https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/tree/master/Source/NFX/Glue).

It is way faster than WCF for coupled systems.

[Interprocess communication with Glue Blog](http://blog.aumcode.com/2014/08/nfxglue-interprocess-communication.html)

[Benchmark](http://blog.aumcode.com/2015/03/apache-thrift-vs-nfxglue-benchmark.html)

Code: https://github.com/aumcode/nfx

Comment: where is documentations?